# C++ Framework for creating servers?

Tags: c++, io

What is (are) modern frameworks for async IO, threading, etc. on C++?

I'am familiar with [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html) but it was long ago, what is the the weapon of choice now?

Answer (score 2):

What about [BOOST libraries](http://www.boost.org/)? It seems to be the most ubiquitous option right now.

It has [threading](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread.html) and [ASYNC-IO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) built in and many, many more libraries.

Comment: Which of the boost parts would serve for async server?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://sites.google.com/site/kinalibangon/ventures/cpp/boost-on-using-asynchronous-i-o-library-for-a-simple-web-server-implementation

Comment: @izhak: [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is the library for that. For threading, there's the C++11 standard library.

Comment: If you are looking for examples, here you have 4 flavors of HTTP server demonstrating different approaches: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Poco C++ Framework and its network library:
http://pocoproject.org/documentation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [Pulsar Server Framework](https://www.pulsarframework.com/). Main benefit is it is built over libuv network libary (used by node.js) that uses asynchronous I/O based on event loops. The frame

1. It’s perfectly scalable. You can just go adding servers as your user
   base increases.
2. It is designed to work with server farm.
3. Highly configurable and easy to use

Currently it has been built for Windows x64 server.